# How to convert a Matrix to a vector in a row-wise order in Julia?

Tags: julia

Considering the following Matrix:

```
julia> mat = [
       1 3 5
       2 4 6
       ]
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6
```

I expect the following vector:

```
 1
 3
 5
 2
 4
 6
```

How can one do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to transpose the matrix and then turn it to a vector (Thanks to [Dan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297185/how-to-convert-a-matrix-to-a-vector-in-a-row-wise-order-in-julia/77297186?noredirect=1#comment136270396_77297186)):

```
julia> mat |> permutedims |> vec
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3
 5
 2
 4
 6
```

Comment: Just mentioning that `permutedims` instead of `transpose` is sometimes preferable as it does not transpose the elements. And there is no real need to `collect` (materialize) the new array unless it is beneficial to do so (in terms of speed and further processing).

Comment: @DanGetz, Thank you so much! I just forgot about the `permutedims`! Great.

Comment: Just not that `transpose` does not allocate while `permutedims` allocates. Hence in that  case `transpose` would be several times faster since `vec(transpose(mat))` does not allocate at all